# Is there a PDF viewer that supports password protected files (username and password)?

Tags: software-recommendation, password, pdf

I need a pdf viewer that supports password protected files, I don't want to crack the files or anything like that I have the required information. The thing is that Document Viewer asks for a password when I try to open these files but does not ask for a username which is required to view the file, so even if I type the password the file won't open. When at work I can open the file using Adobe Reader but the Ubutnu version (Adobe REader 9) says that I need a plugin to use such functions.
Thanks

Comment: i am not aware that pdf files can be protected with two levels of protection (username and password). generally its a single password, which has nothing to do with the username and password of your system. ;)

Comment: Yes, it is commonly used by companies who want to restrict access to their files and can easily remoe said access by deleting the provided account.

Comment: Ok. I have a query now. If your company IT ninjas have control over the access of the pdf, then how is it possible to open it outside of your company network. Just imagine a situation, where a user's access were revoked but he is able to open the pdf from his home PC using the credentials that he had. Will this scenario be possible? My apologies for deviating from the main topic.

Comment: I have not seen this either (user name + password) on a PDF, I have seen password only. Perhaps adobe has a product.

Comment: They don't have control thing is file is in a Data Site, you download it and for opening it it requires you to input same username/password as for the data site, I don't really understand the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been searching around a bit and I'm not finding that Adobe supports this type of encryption/password.

Adobe's site says there are two levels of protection, both with just a password:
http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/securing-pdfs-passwords.html

What software is your company using to create these PDFs?  This might give us a lead on how they are doing it.  My guess is that it's not actually a PDF file but some sort of wrapper that encases the PDF file and then integrates with your company's active directory?

Edit:  It looks like this company makes an Adobe supported plugin that is doing what you are describing:
http://plugin.fileopen.com/faq.aspx

If it's not this company, it's likely someone similar.  Given that, you're going to have to find out if the company making this plugin you're using has a client app for Ubuntu/Linux.  The plugin (at least how these people have designed it) is interfacing to a server on your network (active directory?) and retrieving credentials.  It's a pretty custom solution; it's not likely a PDF reader is going to support this natively.

Comment: Yes it is using that plug-in. Thanks a lot!